# I want to optimize this short loop in php

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

this code is working but is there a better way for it to make it shorter

```
        if ($request->has('images')) {
            $images = [];
            foreach ($data['images'] as $image) {
                $images[] = UploadImage::uploadImageToStorage($image, 'Feeds/store/' . $data['store_id']);
            }
            $data['images'] = $images;
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Shorter code does not necessarily make your code more efficient.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You could add an `uploadImagesToStorage()` method to your `UploadImage` class. Note the plural: "images". This way you don't have to use a loop everything time when you want to upload multiple images. Of course the `uploadImagesToStorage()` method still has a loop inside.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is must such. But i cannot check it. Please check it yourself.

```php
$images = collect($data['images']??[])->function($image) use($data){
    return UploadImage::uploadImageToStorage($image, 'Feeds/store/' . $data['store_id']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to get this done.

```php
$data['images'] = array_map(
  fn($image) => UploadImage::uploadImageToStorage($image, 'Feeds/store/' . $data['store_id']),
  $request->input('images', []) // if "images" cannot be found or empty an array (empty) will be returned
);
```

> `Laravel`'s [`Illuminate\Http\Request`](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Http/Request.html)`::`[`input($key = null, $default = null)`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#retrieving-an-input-value) accepts a second argument that will be returned in case the `$key` cannot be found in the request values. In the above code, if `images` is not found or empty, an `array` will be returned.